# Error while compiling in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have compiled the below code :

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;

template <uint8 N> inline uint8 g(uint8 x) { return x > N ? 1 : 0; }

template <size_t stride, size_t boxsize, class T, class F>
  inline void boxfilt(size_t width, size_t size, T * inout, const F & f) {

  }
  template <class T> inline T self(const T & x) { return x; }
  template <size_t stride, size_t boxsize, class T>
  inline void boxfilt(size_t width, size_t size, T * inout) {
    return boxfilt<stride, boxsize>(width, size, inout, self<T>);
  }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint8 *out = NULL;
    boxfilt<3,4>(10,29,out,g<4>);

    return 0;
}
```

In g++ compiler, it works fine. When I try to compile the same code in Visual Studio 2008 compiler, it shows the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2780: 'void boxfilt(size_t,size_t,T *)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided   g:\testfjx\test\test.cpp    
Error   2   error C2784: 'void boxfilt(size_t,size_t,T *,const F &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'    g:\testfjx\test\test.cpp    
Error   3   error C2784: 'void boxfilt(size_t,size_t,T *,const F &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from 'uint8 *'  g:\testfjx\test\test.cpp
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @MM. it works well in visual c++ 2008. but why not in visual c++ 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK, in Visual C++ 2008 too.

If both VC++2008 and G++4.7.2 accept the code and VC++2005 doesn't, so maybe VC++2005 has bug, maybe it doesn't implement C++ specification completely.